# How to concat videos and images with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation

I have videos and images. I want to concatenate them. And I want the images to be displayed for specific duration, say 10 seconds.
If I first convert image to video and concate, it works

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 10 -i missing.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p 7.mp4 

ffmpeg -y -i 5.mp4 -i 7.mp4 -i 2.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v2];[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" -c:v libx264 -r 30 output.mkv
```

But I want to do it with one ffmpeg command.
for example

```
ffmpeg -y -i 5.mp4 -loop 1 -t 10 -i missing.png -i 5.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1,format=yuv420p,fps=30[v0];[1]format=yuv420p,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1,fps=30[v1];[2:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1,format=yuv420p,fps=30[v2];[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

I expected above command to be working but it didn't. It only concate the first video and 10 seconds of image. Only a few frames of the  third video were added and the duration of output video was only 20 seconds. I expected it to be 30 seconds.

Please help me what is wrong or provide me such ffmpeg command
Thanks